# How to append multiple text files together and then split them?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to append text files together with there file names, then split them apart.

I have been able to append files together using tail, but unsure whether this is the best method.

```
MacBook-Pro:test torn$ ls
file1   file2   file3   file4
MacBook-Pro:test torn$ cat *
this is file 1
this is file 2
this is file 3
this is file 4
MacBook-Pro:test torn$ tail -n +1 * > allFiles
MacBook-Pro:test torn$ cat allFiles 
==> file1 <==
this is file 1

==> file2 <==
this is file 2

==> file3 <==
this is file 3

==> file4 <==
this is file 4
MacBook-Pro:test torn$
```

How can I split allFiles back into the original files?

Comment: What's your [ultimate goal](http://xyproblem.info/)? Does the intermediate file need to be readable? A tarball would be an easier way to package files together.

Comment: [What are you trying to do? prepend the filename to the file?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: @JohnKugelman I require the intermediate file to be readable.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I want to be able to package many files together, and then unpackage them. but whiles packaged they need to be readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most strightforward is probably `grep`, because it prepends the file name to every line.

```
bash$ grep ^ one two three /dev/null
one:first line
one:
one:^ empty line
two:
three:^ look, two only contained one empty line
three:this one contains three lines, too
three:quod erat demonstrandum.
```

Splitting them back out is a trivial task with Awk:

```
awk -F : '$1 != p { if(p) close(p) }
    { print substr($0,length($1)+1 >$1
        p=$1 }' combined.txt
```

Adding `/dev/null` to the `grep` arguments in order to ensure that it always gets more than a single file name argument is an old hack; you can certainly use `grep -H` on any remotely modern system for the same effect.

Comment: `awk -F :`? verses `-f` (which looks for progname?)

Answer (score 0):

For spliting files you may use [split](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/usplit.htm) or [csplit](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucsplit.htm) utilities, for joining files [join](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ujoin.htm)

How to use `join` ? Perhaps like below:

```sh
$ cat a.txt
ala
ola
ewa
$ cat b.txt
ula
ewa
$ (echo -e "\n";cat a.txt)|awk 'BEGIN{s=0;}{print NR+s" "$0}'
1
2
3 ala
4 ola
5 ewa
$ (echo -e "\n";cat a.txt)|awk 'BEGIN{s=0;}{print NR+s" "$0}'>a1.txt
$ (cat b.txt;echo -e "\n\n")|awk 'BEGIN{s=0;}{print NR+s" "$0}'
1 ula
2 ewa
3
4
5
$ (cat b.txt;echo -e "\n\n")|awk 'BEGIN{s=0;}{print NR+s" "$0}'>b1.txt
$ join a1.txt b1.txt|awk '{$1="";print}'|sed 's/ //g'
ula
ewa
ala
ola
ewa
```

Comment: Can you show how to use the commands? `csplit` is useful but I don't see how `split` or `join` help.

Comment: How can I use split or csplit to split "allFiles" at each of the file names "==> file1 <==" and name that file "file1"?